# How to add a floating image so that it remains visible on the screen regardless of scrolling?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I am working on bootstrap home page. I wanted to add a floating ribbon image (Buy Now) just like:

http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/ website.

[image]

I tried to add it into my webpage but it does not appears. I know that I have to use `Fixed` and `Top` Property in CSS but I am not getting the image only. I added the buy ribbon link below form. May I added it into a wrong place. I am new to Bootstrap.

[image]

Code:

```css
#buy-now-ribbon {
    /*background: url(images/ribbon.png) no-repeat;*/
    background: url("http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/wp-content/themes/sky/images/ribbon.png") no-repeat;

    top: -8px;
    right: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 222;
    width: 53px;
    height: 145px;
    display: none;
}

#backgroundimage {
    background-image: url("https://d12dkjq56sjcos.cloudfront.net/pub/media/wysiwyg/Dubai-Skyline-Burj-Al-Arab-Big-Bus-Tours-01.17.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <a href="http://themeforest.net/item/sky-wordpress-listings-theme/10061836?ref=Cohhe" target="_blank" class="buy-now-ribbon"></a>
        <div class="container-fullwidth example2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com">
                            <img src="images/layout/check.png" style="width:451px;height:36px;" class="img-responsive" alt="dubaiexporters.com"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Advertise</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Exhibitions
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Trade fairs in U.A.E</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Trade fairs worldwide</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Add Your Event</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Memberships</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Partners</a>
                            </li>
                            <%--     <li><a href="#"></a></li>--%>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!--/.container-fluid -->
            </nav>

            <div id="backgroundimage"></div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: they use image do you have image?

Comment: yes..i have used it in CSS..

Answer (score 2):

I know your problem - a class/ID mix-up. In your CSS, you've got this line:

```
#buy-now-ribbon
```

But in your HTML, this line pops up:

```
<a href="http://themeforest.net/item/sky-wordpress-listings-theme/10061836?ref=Cohhe"
   target="_blank" class="buy-now-ribbon"></a>
```

The problem you're having is your ID selector (#) does not link with your class declaration (`class="buy-now-ribbon`). The selector for a class is a dot/period (.). In your CSS, change the `#buy-now-ribbon` to `.buy-now-ribbon`, and it will work.

Comment: i made the changes that you have mentioned here but still the problem persists....

Comment: Can you describe how? Like, a link to the website, or an image/video of what is wrong?

Comment: https://ibb.co/gtvL7y...... Kindly check this link...while inspecting on class floatingbanner,it shows the div area..but the image is not there....

Comment: Ok, I'll check it ASAP tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the response @JBDouble05.....but i found out the answer...:)

Comment: Good! Did I help in any way? If I did, would you mind marking me as the solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173469/discussion-between-jbdouble05-and-chetan-kambli).

Answer (score 2):

I added this CSS:

```
.buy-now-ribbon{
    background:url(images/ribbon.png) no-repeat;
     /*background: url("http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/wp-content/themes/sky/images/ribbon.png") no-repeat;*/
 top:0;
 left:0px;
 position:fixed;
 width:10%;
 z-index:9999;
 height:150px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I made some changes here.I have placed div after ul class and it worked for me.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        ...
        ...                   
</ul>
 <a href="" target="_blank" class="buy-now-ribbon"></a>
```